# Autosave editor notes with onchange event hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, quill

Found a solution for autosaving with Quill text editor:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lance-Jernigan/pen/qrxmpp?editors=0010)
Went on trying to fit it to React hooks useState, see beneath. Got an error with this solution:

"State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()."

Any ideas how I could have the onChange still trigger the autosaving with Hooks state?

```
  const [timeOut, setTimeOut] = useState(null);
  const [notesWritten, setNotesWritten] = useState(''); // Value:
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState('');


  const resetTimeout = (id, newID) => {
    clearTimeout(id);
    return newID;
  };

  const saveValue = () => {
    setSaved(true);
    setTimeOut(() => setSaved(false), 1000);
  };

  const editValue = (textWritten) => {
    setTimeOut(resetTimeout(timeOut, setTimeOut(saveValue, 400)), setNotesWritten(textWritten));
  };


  return (
      <ReactQuill
        value={notes}
        // onChange={value => onChange(value)}
        onChange={(value) => {
          onChange(value);
          editValue(value);
        }}
      />
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, by picking apart the nested setStates: `this.setState({timeout: resetTimeout(this.state.timeout, setTimeout(this.saveValue, 400)), value: value})` from the original solution. Like this:

```
  const [timeOutValue, setTimeOutValue] = useState(null);
  const [notesWritten, setNotesWritten] = useState(''); // Value:

  const resetTimeout = (id, newID) => {
    clearTimeout(id);
    return newID;
  };

  const saveValue = () => {
    saveNotes();
  };

  const editValue = (textWritten) => {
    setTimeOutValue(resetTimeout(timeOutValue, setTimeout(saveValue, 1000)));
    setNotesWritten(textWritten);
  };

return (
      <ReactQuill
        value={notes}
        // onChange={value => onChange(value)}
        onChange={(value) => {
          onChange(value);
          editValue(value);
        }}
      />
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300,bigTimeout){
  let timer;
  let t = (new Date()).getTime(); 
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if((new Date()).getTime()-t>bigTimeout){
       t = (new Date()).getTime();
       func.apply(this,args);
     }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
    func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
const func = debonuce(yourFunc,2000,1000);
...
func(...args)
```